# Polyembryonic Honey Mango seedlings don’t look too good

Tags: seedlings

My seedlings we’re doing good but now leaves are blackening at the base and at the tips. I recently moved the seed to a pot with drainage holes. I am using some organic bug pesticide. I have gnat    Problems.[image]

Comment: Another picture https://imgur.com/gallery/2TSQLeR

Answer (score 1):

There is too much wood product in the soil. The soil is killing the mango seedling. Put it in different soil. I find that the best soil mix for mango trees is a 50/50 mix of peat an perlite and you can also add sand to it. Once you do that they will grow like weeds.